# While reading repository properties file getting error response as: The method click() is undefined for the type Object

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Code isn't able to read Properties file. It returns validation error message in response;

> The method `click()` is undefined for the type Object

```
Properties obj = new Properties();
    FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\application.properties");
    obj.load(objfile);
    
 // Navigate to link Mobile Testing and Back

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("MobileTesting"))).click();
    driver.navigate().back();

 // Enter Data into Form

    driver.findElement(By.id(obj.getProperty("EmailTextBox"))).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id(obj.getProperty("SignUpButton"))).click();
```

Comment: Can you paste your exception? Your code seems okay hence it might be not representative

Comment: Exception is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method click() is undefined for the type Object
 The method back() is undefined for the type Object
 The method sendKeys(String) is undefined for the type Object
 The method click() is undefined for the type Object

 at com.objectrepository.demo.DemoOR.main(DemoOR.java:33)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will solve your problem, but I see that you have two path separators in your properties file path which may be causing an issue. I would remove them and use a more OS-agnostic solution:

```
FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "application.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line in your code

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("MobileTesting"))).click();
```

with

```
String b = obj.getProperty("MobileTesting");
driver.get(b); //b is the link for MobileTesting.
```

Let me know if you need any info otherwise in comments.